# ODBC How to store a variable length array of strings?

Tags: mysql, odbc

Y.A.N.Q. (yet another n00b question).

I have managed to design my db, defining tables & columns. I have even got code to access the db, yay!

Now, one bit that I haven't yet gotten to in the "MySql weekend crash course".

Let's say that I want to store something like "notes" which is a TStringList sort of thing. A list of strings which might be a different number of strings every time I submit a new set of data to the db.

How should I best handle that? Should I just concatenate the strings into one when writing and split them when reading back out? That way I would only need one TEXT column.

Or is there a preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application..  One option is having two tables, Notebook and Note, and a [1-many](http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_1tox.html) relationship between them.  So one notebook can have many notes.  Each note consists of a string, and maybe a date created, or something else to use for ordering.  Of course, Notebook could really be any table.

EDIT: Yes, I think you're on the right track. It could be:

```
Notebook:
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

Note:
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
  notebook_id INTEGER
  note_text VARCHAR(1024)
```

You could rename and add fields to each.  For example, Notebook could be anything that needs notes attached (e.g. Project), and it could have other project attributes (e.g. a deadline).  Note could have a date if you want to be able to order them other than by id.

Comment: +1 I think I see what you are saying, and I probably just haven't gotten on the chapter for one to many yet.  But I can imagine it... I guess that the point is that each string would have to have a unique Id (maybe a GUID, or just mark the column as AUTO INCREMENT)?

Or did I just get that 180 wrong? Shouldn't each string have a column identifying the primary key of the corresponding `notebook` ?

And chance of a mini-example? just a notebook with a two line note - declarations of tables and columns? That might help me to grasp it.

Comment: any chance of a simple example, Matthew? Sorry to ask. You will be awarded the answer in any case ;-)